# Trouble with jquery additional methods validation - getting both messages

Tags: jquery

I know that the additional methods plugin will allow you to set multiple form fields in a group, set how many fields are required to validate the group and (most importantly in this instance) only display a single message in the case of an error.

I've done it before but cannot make it work right even in this miniscule example and would appreciate a pointer as to where I'm missing the mark and what I need to change to only show a single error.

As always, many thanks in advance.  Test code is below or I have a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43rdworld/darwjeo8/)** of the same thing.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            div {float:left;width:110px;}
            input[type=text] {width:100px;}
            #nameError {width:500px;}
            #submitWrapper {clear:both;margin-top:20px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="testForm" id="testForm" method="post" action="">
            <div><input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" class="names22" value="" placeholder="First Name"></div>
            <div><input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" class="names22" value="" placeholder="Last Name"></div>
            <div id="nameError"></div>
            <div id="submitWrapper"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
        </form>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#testForm").validate({
                    groups: {
                        fullName:  "fName,lName"
                    },
                    rules: {
                        fName: {
                            require_from_group: [2, ".names22"]
                        },
                        lName: {
                            require_from_group: [2, ".names22"]
                        }
                    },
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        if (element.hasClass("names22")) {
                            error.appendTo("#nameError");
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        fName: {
                            require_from_group: "* Both fields required1"
                        },
                        lName: {
                            require_from_group: "* Both fields required2"
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to remove the comma from the *groups* section:

```
groups: {
   fullName:  "fName lName"
},
```

and I would also suggest making the error messages the same:

```
messages: {
   fName: {
      require_from_group: "* Both fields required"
   },
   lName: {
      require_from_group: "* Both fields required"
   }
}
```

If you are carrying out further validation, you may want to update the *errorPlacement* section to specifically detect if handling an error on *fullName*:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
   if (element.attr("name") == "fName" || element.attr("name") == "lName" ) {
      error.insertAfter("#lName");
   } else {
     error.insertAfter(element);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I feel like an idiot for missing that.  I had done it before with a lot of groups and one of the groups had commas - the one I never used.  So I've been referring to the wrong one all this time.  It works a whole lot better without the comma.  I had different messages because I was curious as to which one gets displayed when using the groups - which I now see is the second one.  Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem - feel free to mark the above as the answer if you think the issue is resolved.